# How to toggle display style using vanilla JS on multiple elements

Tags: javascript

I wasn't sure how to write that question logically, I pretty much figured the togglw out, but I struggle with something else. When I click on one element and open it, I want to click on another one to open and the previously opened to close. It doesn't work, however. Whenever I click on another element, the opened one just closes without opening the other. Basically, I want to close the element only when I click on that specific element. Or when I click on another one (which kinda works) but in this case also want the other to open, if that makes sense. I am stuck at this point.

Thanks for any help.

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/danosvk/pen/JjLEGMK

Here is my code:

```js
    const questions = document.querySelectorAll("section");
    const answers = document.querySelectorAll(".answer");
    
    toggle = false
    function open() {
      for (let i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        answers[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    toggle = !toggle
      this.lastElementChild.style.display = toggle ? "block" : "none"
    }
    
    questions.forEach((question) => question.addEventListener("click", open));
```

```css
    .card {
      width: 20.4375rem;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border-radius: 1.4375rem;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 132px 24px 48px;
      text-align: center;
      transform: translateY(-125px);
    }
    
    section {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8ea;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    p {
      color: var(--main-text-color);
      font-size: 0.75rem;
    }
    
    .answer {
      flex-basis: 100%;
      text-align: left;
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="card">
      <h1 class="no">faq</h1>
      <section>
        <p class="question">How many team members can i invite?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
          You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no
          limit on team members for the Premium plan.
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <p class="question">What is the maximum file upload size?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
          No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted
          storage space.
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <p class="question">How do I reset my password?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
          Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password” from
          your profile page. A reset link will be emailed to you.
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <p class="question">Can I cancel my subscription?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
          Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions
          asked.
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <p class="question">Do you provide additional support?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
          Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during
          normal business hours.
        </p>
      </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `toggle` won't work as it is always `false` when an answer is showing.

Instead, save the style of the clicked option **before** wiping all the answers, and then use it to determine whether or not to show the answer.

If `this.lastElementChild.style.display` is `''` (i.e. on the first time the menu is clicked), it is set to `none`.

```js
    const questions = document.querySelectorAll("section");
    const answers = document.querySelectorAll(".answer");
    
    function open() {

      currentDisplay=this.lastElementChild.style.display||'none';

      for (let i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        answers[i].style.display = "none";
      }

      if (currentDisplay=='none') this.lastElementChild.style.display = "block"

    }
    
    questions.forEach((question) => question.addEventListener("click", open));
```

```css
    .card {
      width: 20.4375rem;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border-radius: 1.4375rem;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 132px 24px 48px;
      text-align: center;
      transform: translateY(-125px);
    }
    
    section {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8ea;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    p {
      color: var(--main-text-color);
      font-size: 0.75rem;
    }
    
    .answer {
      flex-basis: 100%;
      text-align: left;
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="card">
      <h1 class="no">faq</h1>
      <section>
        <p class="question">How many team members can i invite?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
          You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no
          limit on team members for the Premium plan.
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <p class="question">What is the maximum file upload size?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
          No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted
          storage space.
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <p class="question">How do I reset my password?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
          Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password” from
          your profile page. A reset link will be emailed to you.
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <p class="question">Can I cancel my subscription?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
          Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions
          asked.
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <p class="question">Do you provide additional support?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
          Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during
          normal business hours.
        </p>
      </section>
```

Comment: Probably the best solution here, I like this a lot. But could you explain what .style.display||'none' actually means? Especially the || symbol...is it 'or' operator? How exactly does it work here?

Comment: It's `logicalOR`. `this.lastElementChild.style.display` on the first run is `''`, which is a falsey value, so JS then evaluates the value as 'none'. After that,  `this.lastElementChild.style.display` is either `none` or `block`, both of which are truey values,  so the right-hand side of the `||` ooerator isn't needed.

Comment: I see, it makes sense now, thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by using this CSS rule to show the answers rather than changing their style inline:

```css
.expanded .answer {
    display: block;
}
```

...and then using event delegation on the `.card` element that contains the FAQ to catch clicks anywhere within it; if the click passed through a `section`, do this:

- If the `section` has the `expanded` class, remove it to un-expand the answer.
- If the `section` doesn't have the `expanded` class, remove it from any other section that has it, then add it to the `section` that was clicked.

Here's the JavaScript part:

```js
const card = document.querySelector(".card");
card.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const section = event.target.closest("section");
    if (section) {
        if (section.classList.contains("expanded")) {
            // This is the expanded one, un-expand it
            section.classList.remove("expanded");
        } else {
            // This isn't the expanded one, un-expand the expanded
            // one (if any) and expand this one
            document.querySelector("section.expanded")?.classList.remove("expanded");
            section.classList.add("expanded");
        }
    }
});
```

Notice the optional chaining on the `querySelector` looking for an expanded section; it's there in case there is no expanded section yet.

Live Example:

```js
const card = document.querySelector(".card");
card.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const section = event.target.closest("section");
    if (section) {
        if (section.classList.contains("expanded")) {
            // This is the expanded one, un-expand it
            section.classList.remove("expanded");
        } else {
            // This isn't the expanded one, un-expand the expanded
            // one (if any) and expand this one
            document.querySelector("section.expanded")?.classList.remove("expanded");
            section.classList.add("expanded");
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.card {
    width: 20.4375rem;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 1.4375rem;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 132px 24px 48px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateY(-125px);
}

section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8ea;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p {
    color: var(--main-text-color);
    font-size: 0.75rem;
}

.answer {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
}

.expanded .answer {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <h1 class="no">faq</h1>
    <section>
        <p class="question">How many team members can i invite?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
            You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team
            members for the Premium plan.
        </p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <p class="question">What is the maximum file upload size?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
            No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.
        </p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <p class="question">How do I reset my password?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
            Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password” from your profile page.
            A reset link will be emailed to you.
        </p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <p class="question">Can I cancel my subscription?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
            Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions asked.
        </p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <p class="question">Do you provide additional support?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
            Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal business
            hours.
        </p>
    </section>
</div>
```

It might be worth adding a class to the `section` and using that in the selectors, in case you have other parts of the page using `section`, like this:

```js
const card = document.querySelector(".card");
card.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const section = event.target.closest(".faq");
    if (section) {
        if (section.classList.contains("expanded")) {
            // This is the expanded one, un-expand it
            section.classList.remove("expanded");
        } else {
            // This isn't the expanded one, un-expand the expanded
            // one (if any) and expand this one
            document.querySelector(".faq.expanded")?.classList.remove("expanded");
            section.classList.add("expanded");
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.card {
    width: 20.4375rem;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 1.4375rem;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 132px 24px 48px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateY(-125px);
}

section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8ea;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p {
    color: var(--main-text-color);
    font-size: 0.75rem;
}

.answer {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
}

.expanded .answer {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <h1 class="no">faq</h1>
    <section class="faq">
        <p class="question">How many team members can i invite?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
            You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team
            members for the Premium plan.
        </p>
    </section>
    <section class="faq">
        <p class="question">What is the maximum file upload size?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
            No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.
        </p>
    </section>
    <section class="faq">
        <p class="question">How do I reset my password?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
            Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password” from your profile page.
            A reset link will be emailed to you.
        </p>
    </section>
    <section class="faq">
        <p class="question">Can I cancel my subscription?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
            Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions asked.
        </p>
    </section>
    <section class="faq">
        <p class="question">Do you provide additional support?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
            Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal business
            hours.
        </p>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: This is pretty simple and clever at the same time. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can also fix it by simply keeping a reference (`currentlyOpen`) of the currently opened section and using it in your event listener.

It would only require you to change some js and keep the same css.

Here's a little bit of code to explaining the change:

```js
let currentlyOpen; // Keep track of the currently openend section.

function toggle() {
    if (currentlyOpen) {
    // Something currently open
    currentlyOpen.lastElementChild.style.display = "none" // Close it
  }
  
  if (currentlyOpen === this) {
    // The element the user clicked on is already opened, close it!
    currentlyOpen.lastElementChild.style.display = "none" // Close it
    currentlyOpen = undefined; // Delete it's refrence
    return // And return (stop execution)
  }
  
  // Show clicked element
  this.lastElementChild.style.display = "block"
  
  // Store it for later
  currentlyOpen = this
}
```

For more info see the code snipped:

```js
const questions = document.querySelectorAll("section");
const answers = document.querySelectorAll(".answer");

let currentlyOpen;

function toggle() {
    if (currentlyOpen) {
    // Something currently open
    currentlyOpen.lastElementChild.style.display = "none" // Close it
  }
  
  if (currentlyOpen === this) {
    // Element is already open
    currentlyOpen.lastElementChild.style.display = "none" // Hide it
    currentlyOpen = undefined; // Delete it's refrence
    return // And return
  }
  
  // Show clicked element
  this.lastElementChild.style.display = "block"
  
  // Store it for later
  currentlyOpen = this
}


questions.forEach((question) => question.addEventListener("click", toggle));
```

```css
.card {
  width: 20.4375rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 1.4375rem;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 132px 24px 48px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-125px);
}

section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8ea;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p {
  color: var(--main-text-color);
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

.answer {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
      <h1 class="no">faq</h1>
      <section>
        <p class="question">How many team members can i invite?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
          You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no
          limit on team members for the Premium plan.
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <p class="question">What is the maximum file upload size?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
          No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted
          storage space.
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <p class="question">How do I reset my password?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
          Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password” from
          your profile page. A reset link will be emailed to you.
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <p class="question">Can I cancel my subscription?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
          Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions
          asked.
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <p class="question">Do you provide additional support?</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
        <p class="answer">
          Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during
          normal business hours.
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>
```

Or a working version hosted on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fmr9tvw8/

Comment: Even simpler solution, wow, this looks good, thank you for your effort, you definitely helped me a lot.